# No downtime upgrade Elasticache from Redis 2.6 to 2.8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to determine whether updating my Elasticache cluster to use Redis 2.8 instead of 2.6 will cause Elasticache downtime. Ideally the upgrade would occur during the cluster's scheduled downtime, but I can't seem to find any documentation on what will happen when I tell the cluster to upgrade.

Has anyone gone through this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have done an upgrade to our redis elasticache. We made a snapshot of the current cache then spawned a new instance from the created snapshot. We pointed the servers to use the new cache then proceeded with the upgrade on the old cache. It did not take some time and the data was still intact but I cannot guarantee it because it was stated in the prompt before the upgrade that the data might be lost during the upgrade.